# Maximum integer set with distinct subset product

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Given a positive integer $N$, how do we find the largest subset $S$ of $ \{1,\dots,N\} $ such that the products of subsets of $S$ are distinct?

I tried listing out some small sets, but seems that when the set is small it is good to keep the primes in $S$, but with larger sets it is better to have primes removed. I'm currently trying to figure out how to interpret "products are distinct", e.g. for $A,B\subset S$, the set of prime factors of numbers in them and multiplicity of those primes should be different.

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A325859